# How use UIPicker with more than one text field

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, textbox, uipickerview

I can get a text box value from a picker to one text box. How do I get a different values to more text boxes.  At present all the text fields get filled even if im only filling out one text box and  only display the values from first NSArray.  I tried an `if` statement, Apple documentation not much help.

I have no idea how tagging works but noted it was mentioned when researching this. Apologies if I haven't explained this properly heres a test app to download if I havnt made much sense that explains it better

[APP example](http://cl.ly/0R2m2q3Q463T)

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource,    UIPickerViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>

{
//decalre picker
UIPickerView *select;



//declare NSArrray
NSArray *arrStatus;
NSArray *arrStatus2;


 }

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *text1;
 - (IBAction)Value:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *text2;
@end
```

.m

```
     - (void)viewDidLoad
 {



///create picker//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

select = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
select.delegate = self;
select.dataSource = self;
[select setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
text1.inputView = select;
text2.inputView = select;



////arrays & objects
arrStatus = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",nil];
arrStatus2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",nil];

//number of colums and rows etc of picker    
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
//One column
return 1;
}

 -(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent: (NSInteger)component
{
//set number of rows
return arrStatus.count;
 return arrStatus2.count;

  }

  -(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
 {
//set item per row
return [arrStatus objectAtIndex:row];
return [arrStatus2 objectAtIndex:row];


- (IBAction)Value:(id)sender {

///get picker values to text field
NSInteger selectedRow = [select selectedRowInComponent:0];

text1.text = [arrStatus objectAtIndex: selectedRow];
[text1 resignFirstResponder];

text2.text = [arrStatus2 objectAtIndex: selectedRow];
[text2 resignFirstResponder];


 }

 @end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the method for didselectrow I had my if statement see which text field was the first responder.  Then used the following code.  It places the uipicker value in each of the text fields.

```
-(void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
if ([_input1 isFirstResponder])
{
    NSString *resultString1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[gradeArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]];
    NSString *resultString2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[plusMinusArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]]];
    NSString *gradeResult = [resultString1 stringByAppendingString:resultString2];
    _input1.text = gradeResult;
}else if ([_input2 isFirstResponder])
{
    NSString *resultString1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[gradeArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]];
    NSString *resultString2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[plusMinusArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]]];
    NSString *gradeResult = [resultString1 stringByAppendingString:resultString2];
    _input2.text = gradeResult; 
}else if ([_inputM isFirstResponder])
{
    NSString *resultString1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[gradeArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]];
    NSString *resultString2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[plusMinusArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]]];
    NSString *gradeResult = [resultString1 stringByAppendingString:resultString2];
    _inputM.text = gradeResult;
}else if ([_input3 isFirstResponder])
{
    NSString *resultString1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[gradeArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]];
    NSString *resultString2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[plusMinusArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]]];
    NSString *gradeResult = [resultString1 stringByAppendingString:resultString2];
    _input3.text = gradeResult;
}else if ([_input4 isFirstResponder])
{
    NSString *resultString1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[gradeArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]];
    NSString *resultString2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[plusMinusArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]]];
    NSString *gradeResult = [resultString1 stringByAppendingString:resultString2];
    _input4.text = gradeResult;
}
}
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT

if you want to get both arrays in the picker, you need to make the columns 2.  This will show both arrays.  I used the following code to display both my arrays in the picker view.

```
-(NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
return 2;
}

-(NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
if (component == 0)
{
    return [gradeArray count];
}
return [plusMinusArray  count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
if (component == 0)
{
    return  [gradeArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
return [plusMinusArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Comment: I also made sure that each text field used the picker for its input view with.                                                                 _input1.inputView = pickerView;
    _input2.inputView = pickerView;
    _inputM.inputView = pickerView;
    _input3.inputView = pickerView;
    _input4.inputView = pickerView;

Comment: Thanks for your reply that was very helpful, I could adapt that so I can now use the text boxes independently which is what I was after. I was not declaring the text boxes as first responders  My only issue now is how to get a different NSArrays. At the moment it only presents the first array. I can ask that in a separate question tho.

Comment: @JSA986, I made an edit, I think this is what you are referring to.  If not, I am glad that I could help a little.